# How to rewrite URL in CodeIgniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-2

I am learning CodeIgniter.I want to rewrite URLs so that `localhost/tutorial/index.php/cart/product` becomes `localhost/tutorial/cart/product`

I tried to edit my .htaccess file inside the application folder with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt)
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$/tutorial/index.php/$1[L]
```

but it didn't work. My CI file name is **tutorial** and CI version is 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried that `.htaccess` file and it seems to work (note the extra spaces in the last line)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tutorial/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your system (in Ubuntu and similar systems you can use `a2enmod rewrite`: it should say that it is already enabled).

Answer (score 2):

I tried and worked for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        # Make sure directory listing is disabled
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        RewriteEngine on
        RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system\/pyrocms\/cache|system\/codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

        # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


    </IfModule>
```